# graph orientation with constraint on incoming degree

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorics

Consider the following graph orientation problem: we would like to orient the edges of a graph G in such a way that each vertex has at most k incoming edges. Prove that this is possible if and only if |E[W]| ≤ k|W| for each subset of vertices W, where E[W] is the set of edges with both endpoints in W.

Answer (score 1):

To show that it is not possible to orient edges if |E[W]| < k|W| comes from [pidgenhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). Every edge is incoming edge for some vertex than there has to be vertex with > k incoming edges.

Other side is done by assuming that it is not possible to orient edges, if |E[W]| <= k|W| holds. Than there is an edge orientation that is 'the best', which means it can't be improved anymore. For that orientation there is a vertex with > k incoming edges, say h. All vertices connected to it by incoming edges has >= h-1 incoming edges, since in other cases we can improve original orientation. Vertices connected to these vertices have >= h-1 >= k incoming vertices, because of possible improvement. By same reasoning, all connected vertices to these vertices also have >= k incoming vertices. Which covers all connected vertices and by summing we have |E[W]| > k|W|, which is a contradiction.